# Disable address bar in Android webview

Tags: android, webview

How do disable and hide the address bar from a WebView?

Comment: Please stop shouting.

Comment: Edited. We can now take our hands off our hears...

Comment: The title was in all capital letters, this is annoying to a lot of users.  As to the question, have you searched through the history? I'm pretty sure this has been answered before.

Comment: hi, i wasnt aware it was in caps. my mistake and yes i searched and could not find a solution. Now i have though thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no address bar in a `WebView`.

If you think you have a `WebView`, and you see an address bar, that is not your `WebView`. Rather, you are looking at the Browser application. Most likely, the URL you told the `WebView` to load did a redirect, and you did not intercept that redirect using a `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideURLLoading()`.

Comment: browser application? i did not call an intent to launch the browser application. i basically used a xml layout with just a single webview that fills the screen an i simple call LoaUrl to that webview.

followed this example from the sdk http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: @jonney: As I wrote, most likely, the URL you told the `WebView` to load did a redirect, and you did not intercept that redirect using a `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideURLLoading()`. A redirect or click on a link will load the resulting URL in the user's choice of browser, unless you use `WebViewClient` to change that behavior.

Comment: the address given in the android.com site is "google.com" when you go to google.com it redirects to google.lk :D datz why I see address bar.. Now I get it.. thanks a lot.

Comment: more info here on catching redirects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273991/webview-shouldinterceptrequest-example

Answer (score 48):

Adding `myView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());` disabled the address bar for me.

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

...

WebView myView = findViewById(R.id.myExampleView);
myView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myView.loadUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

**XML Snippet**

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/myExampleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

source: (Japanese site): 
http://www.techdoctranslator.com/android/webapps/webview

Answer (score 26):

Finally I Try with this. Its worked for me..

Here is the working code

```
private WebView webview ;   
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ebook);

    //webview use to call own site
    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());          
    webview .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview .getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);      
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
}
```

and your entire main.xml(res/layout) look should like this:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

don't go to add layouts.

Answer (score 18):

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

solved the problem for me..

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin code as following

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
```