# How do I display a large png file and scroll around it?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a large Png image file that I would like to display and scroll around it as I can do in a WebView. When I load my activity with the image file into an ImageView the image is displayed in the screen but is too small to read. I guess the Zoom controls will help once the image it is at it's normal size. I have tried using the image in a WebView but I don't want the Url displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done something similar with a TableLayout.  I wrapped it in a ScrollView nested in a HorizontalScrollView and the user is able to scroll around in all directions when my TableLayout takes up more space than what will fit on the screen.  I imagine this would work with an ImageView as well.  Something like this:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I've tried this but you can only scroll in one direction at once, because two scroll views don't work as one.

Comment: @Lumis What if you extended the HorizontalScrollView, and for each touch event you would return false, in order to send it to the scrollView too ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own [Custom Scrollable Image View](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/custom-scrollable-image-view). I have used this in a game, it works, and you can scroll in x, y directions.

Comment: I like the look of this! how do i link this to my image? i have made the class and added this code but would i have to make a new activity with the image to use this! i am still getting to grips/learning with android

Answer (score 0):

I posted one solution for the same question here: [Images in ScrollView in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990682/images-in-scrollview-in-android/4991692#4991692)

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried a `WebView` but you don't want the URL displayed?  Do you mean that you see an address bar at the top?  If so, please see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136362/disable-address-bar-in-android-webview).