# change position of imageview in layout like facebook cover android

Tags: android, facebook, scroll, imageview

I need to scroll the imageview inside the layout with fixed width and height. If image is not wide enough it win'nt set as cover picture, if it is with same height and width of cover layout then it should not scroll and if it is bigger than that then it should scroll or drag and accordingly its position be set. I am not able to find anything like this. I need an idea or solution for this.

Comment: I think you have to look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031097/how-do-i-display-a-large-png-file-and-scroll-around-it

Comment: it is working..but not the way I want it to. Thank you :)