# Preventing the display of the URL/GoTo line at the top of the screen

Tags: android, webview

I have almost got WebView working the way I want.
The only thing left to resolve is to not display the URL/GoTo line at the top of the screen
I have :-

```
 <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

in my xml but still that row shows.
Can someone tell me how to get rid of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136362/disable-address-bar-in-android-webview

Comment: Looks like this post could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136362/disable-address-bar-in-android-webview

Comment: Appreciate your answer but is that then saying that the code at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The trick, if it is a trick, is not to allow redirection.
Do `mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stockton.co.za/zars/index.html");`
rather than `mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.stockton.co.za/zars");`

Thanks for the help.