# How to login from an Android app through Tank Auth on a Codeigniter site

Tags: android, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

I have a website which is built on Codeigniter and I use [Tank Auth library](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for login. I'm trying to implement a **login app in Android that uses Tank Auth** but I not have any idea how to do it!

Where can I find any infomation about **Android login and Tank Auth?** or Can you tell me how to do it? please!

I hope someone can give me an answer, please!
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building an Android App that is Native (Java)

a. Then you will have to build a REST API on top your User Data and implement a Register/Login/Activate Account/Resend Code. Writing and Reading from your Database.
You can use Phil Sturgeon's REST API built for Codeigniter
https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restclient

b. Build an Android WebView to wrap your website without the Address bar
[Disable address bar in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136362/disable-address-bar-in-android-webview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @seyz4all!...Yes I'm building an Android App with Java, I have to study the option a), the option b) I don't want to use by performance and usability problems...do you know the codeigniter library called [tank auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/)?...I need to analize how to modify this library to call it from my Android App written in Java, do you have any idea about that? thanks a lot!